# Marking highlight / important notes in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Somehow my searches aren't getting me what I want.

Here's what I need:

When I'm writing code in VS 2010 I often have places where I want to note that something is important that I should be aware of (for e.g. some assumption). Let's say I'm in a method that assumes that I map some strings to enum values and I want to mark it with a note, something like

"remember! We're assuming that...blah blah"

That way, at a later point, I can open 1 single place to see all my assumptions and other important notes for all my code. I don't want to document them in an external text file because I'd like to note it as I code, and the note needs to be near the code.

Is there any such feature? for e.g. //todo seems to list all todo's in the todo tab. I use an extension manager which lets me bookmark with //BMK, but is there anything that I can use for important etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built in tags for task lists using HACK, TODO, and UNDONE
More info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zce12xx2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

To create your own task list tags, see this article
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekwz6akh.aspx

PS If you can't see the environment option, then make sure you check the Show all settings checkbox at the bottom of the tree view... gets me every time.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted! Thank you!